# How to skip building a DACPAC in an SSDT project

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

In my solution, I have an SSDT project. Every time I build my solution, a line stating:

```
1>  Database -> <some\path>\Database\bin\Debug\Database.dacpac
```

shows up, and takes about 20 seconds to complete.

If I decide to use DACPACs in the future, I'll only generate the DACPAC when the database is ready to publish.

Is there any way to continue building the SSDT project, but not generate the DACPAC everytime the project is built, to cut down on build times?

Comment: 20 seconds seems like a long time. How many objects are in your schema?

Answer (score 1):

This might not sound like a good solution but if you are not interested with the Sql Project and dacpac output, for example if you made a code change you just want to test/debug it;

- Right click the project and click "Unload Project".

It is not a real solution, but it can save you that 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Building the dacpac file is part of the SQL Server Database Project's job.  Note that the process of producing the dacpac file does not take long to execute.  Internally most of the time is spent parsing the T-SQL, interpreting the object declarations, building a model representation of the declared database, resolving references between objects, and validating.  The serialization of the model into XML and storing it in a dacpac file would typically not take 20 seconds. I would guess that other things are happening during that time.